# Ruby find a line in a file and add below it

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a text file that I need to edit in a chef recipe.
I need to find this particular line (in bold), and insert configuration below it.

```
.
.
.
# PLACE YOUR CONFIGURATION MEMORY start up here :
<INSERT MEMORY ARGUMENTS HERE>
.
.
.
.
```

Here is what I have been trying..I just would like to know is there some sort of functionality in Ruby
where I could find a line and then below that line add new entry?

```
ruby_block "edit the configuration file " do
  block do 
    text = File.read(file_name)
    replace = text.sub(/# PLACE YOUR CONFIGURATION MEMORY start up here :/, "MEM_ARGS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m");
    File.write(file_name, replace)
  end
end
```

I don't want to replace the comment section though, I just want to make use of it as an anchor where I could add new lines of text.

Answer (score 3):

The correct-er way to do this in Chef is the `line` cookbook, which has resources for managing this kind of in-place file manipulation. However, we strongly recommend against using it as it is very easy to write a bad regex or whatnot and up with a non-convergent system. Managing the whole file with a `template` resource is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
File.open('input') do |i|
  File.open('output', 'w') do |o|
    while line = i.gets
      o.puts line
      if line.chomp == "# PLACE YOUR CONFIGURATION MEMORY start up here:"
        o.puts "MEM_ARGS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
      end
    end
  end
end
`mv output input`
```

How does this work?

- First open the input file, will fail with `Errno::ENOENT` if it does not exist
- Then open the output file
- Streams through them line by line
- Inserts additional lines after marker line, `chomp` removes trailing linebreak
- The `do end` blocks automagically close both files
- Eventually replaces input with `mv`

Comment: For the read file, do you prefer `open` and `gets` to `IO.foreach('input') do |line|...`?

Comment: Good catch, that makes it shorter OTOH `File.open { File.foreach { ... }}`  would create an empty output file if input does not exist rather than just failing.

Comment: I think two types of failures need to be considered: file does not exist; and file does not contain the text marker (including the case of the file being empty).If the file is of manageable size it might be easiest to construct the output file in an array, then write the array to file if all is well.

Comment: This is very incorrect for Chef, please remove this answer.

Comment: @coderanger can you explain why this is incorrect for chef? Happy to update my answer if you can provide more constructive feedback.

Comment: 1) it assumes the input and output files are different, which is not generally the case when someone is trying to do in-place file manipulation 2) the `line` cookbook mentioned below demonstrates a resource-oriented API, using raw Ruby code is only ever done as a fallback for exceptional situations. Over-use of Ruby code leads to unreadable and unmaintainable recipes.

Comment: i.e. this answer cannot be corrected, it's fundamentally incorrect and should be removed.